# Android Spinner Selected Item as a String for a Query

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor, android-spinner, simplecursoradapter

From an answer to a past question of fine, I am getting this far.
I am trying to have the selected item in my spinner that is populated from my SQLite database as a String that is used as a variable for my other queries.

```
//POWERSPORTS TYPE Cursor
    vType = (Cursor) DataBaseHelper.getPowersportsType();
    this.startManagingCursor(vType);

        SimpleCursorAdapter scaType = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, 
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, 
                vType,
                new String [] {DataBaseHelper.POWERSPORTS_TYPE},
                new int[] {android.R.id.text1});

        scaType.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        vTypeSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.typeSpinner);
        vTypeSpinner.setAdapter(scaType);

        vTypeSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener(){

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String typeSelection = vTypeSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
            }
        });

    //POWERSPORTS MAKE Cursor
    vMake = (Cursor) DataBaseHelper.getPowersportsMake(typeSelection);
    this.startManagingCursor(vMake);

        SimpleCursorAdapter scaMake = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, 
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, 
                vMake,
                new String [] {DataBaseHelper.POWERSPORTS_MAKE},
                new int[]{android.R.id.text1});

        scaMake.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        vMakeSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.makeSpinner);
        vMakeSpinner.setAdapter(scaMake);
```

Also, here is my query of the second spinner.

```
public static Cursor getPowersportsMake(String typeSelection){  
return myDataBase.query(POWERSPORTS_TABLE,  
   new String [] {POWERSPORTS_ID, POWERSPORTS_MAKE},  
   POWERSPORTS_TYPE+"='"+typeSelection+"'",  
   null,  
   null,  
   null,  
   null);  
 }
```

I know I am doing something wrong because I am getting typeSelection "cannot be resolved to a variable" within my

```
vMake = (Cursor) DatabaseHelper.getpowersportsMake(typeSelection);
```

How do I use the String that is created from my onItemSelected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare `typeSelection` as global variable. At present it is within `setOnItemSelectedListener` and hence is not visible.

Comment: This would my first time hearing about a global variable. How would I do this?

Comment: You declare it outside your methods.

Comment: Not so sure on how to exactly to do this, but I will Google this and accept your answer. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Made it a global variable, works like a charm, just getting another unwanted result. Thanks for the help.